# How to copy multiple (specific) selected sheets to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched for hours but with no luck.
I want to copy multiple sheets from a file to a new workbook.  Not all sheets but just the ones that I have selected. My selection could be different each time I perform this exercise. The scenario is that I have a master reporting file with say 25 sheets each with a different report. I want to open the file and select reports to send to a user.  I will select say 5 specific reports e.g. sheets 1,10,15,18 and 20 I then want to copy them to a new workbook so I can email them to my customer. Ideally I would paste them into new workbook at values only to remove all formulas and links from reports being sent to customer. The following code works great for a single sheet:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy _
Before:=Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1)
```

What I would like to do is to change the word 'ActiveSheet' to 'SelectedSheets' and keep all else the same.  This does not work. Am I missing something simple?

I have tried to:
a: change code as above
b: record a macro copying selected sheets and using the code (but it provides code for specific sheet names such as sheet2 and sheet3.  This will not work as I need to it be code that works with whatever sheets I select.
c: searched internet for hours. Generally provides as advice on working with all sheets, working with a pre-defined set of selected sheets, working with pre-defined selection using arrays, code to select sheets based on common characteristics e.g. select all sheets with name "R1" in it.

Comment: Why does an array not work if you have specific sheets to copy?

Comment: If you can't use an array, then [`Window.SelectedSheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.selectedsheets) may be useful.

Comment: An array does not work because (I believe) it requires you to edit and identify the specific sheets into the VBA code.  The selected sheets could change each time so I don't want to have to open code and type in multiple sheet names each time.

Comment: Ok, the "specific" then was misleading me.

Comment: The 'Windows.SelectedSheets' suggestions errors saying that "Object doesn't support property or method"  Also the microsoft help function says this approach selects "All" sheets in a workbook.  I just want to work with the specific sheets I have selected.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.  So this answer then assumes there is no way to identify selected sheets and perform an action on them as a selection. Even though you can do it on selected cells in a sheet for example '''Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Just loop through all the sheets in the new workbook and set the `.UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value` on each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Window.SelectedSheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.selectedsheets) here:

> Returns a Sheets collection that represents all the selected sheets in the specified window

<strike>In testing, it seems like you need to loop through the `SelectedSheets`. A one-liner `.Copy` on the entire collection copied over all sheets, not just the selected one(s).</strike>

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
        ws.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Re-tested and I couldn't reproduce the original issue of `SelectedSheets.Copy` copying all the sheets.

```
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets.Copy
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook '<~ this is the new workbook with the copied sheets
```

Comment: argh!! that works.  Thanks so much for your time.  I now have a workable code framework from which I can start when developing similar tasks on multiple sheets.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why explicitly create a workbook then copy the sheets individually when doing a simple copy of the sheets without a target creates a new book anyway? Am I missing something? I have read the OP about 5 times and can't see why anything more than my code below is needed, it retains all formatting and creates a new workbook with the selected sheets and all data is values.

Comment: @DanDonoghue - ignore the first code snippet. For some reason in testing, I originally was getting all the sheets copied over with `.Windows(1).SelectedSheets.Copy`... but I couldn't replicate that today so not sure what happened.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for the explanation, that clears up my confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two distinct requirements here (Copy selected sheets only, and copy values only), I'd suggest looping over the selected sheets, and copy the data one sheet at a time. You may want to copy formatting as well

Some notes:

- Since you want to act on Selected sheets, using `ActiveWindow` is appropriate here
- As you want only values in the destination sheet, I'd avoid a simple Copy Paste as that would copy Formulas, Conditional Formatting, Named Range definitions, any VBA in the sheet module and potentially other stuff too, which you would have to then remove.  Paste only what you want to.
- Don't forget the Sheet Names
- Column Widths can be `PasteSpecial`'d as well if required
- There is no `xlPasteRowHeights` so if that's required you'll need to code it longhand

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Sheets
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    ' reference selected sheets
    Set wks = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    'deselect multiple sheets so Copy will work
    wks.Item(1).Select

    'create new book with one sheet
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    'reference that sheet
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets(1)

    ' loop selected sheets
    For Each wsSrc In wks
        'rename sheet
        wsDest.Name = wsSrc.Name
        ' copy values and formats
        Set rng = wsSrc.UsedRange
        rng.Copy
        With wsDest.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column) ' Used Range might not start at A1
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats      ' optional, if required
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths ' optional, if required
            .Cells.FormatConditions.Delete    ' optional, if CF is not required
        End With

        ' add another sheet if required
        If Not wsSrc Is wks.Item(wks.Count) Then
            Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
        End If
    Next

    wb.SaveAs "C:\Your\Path\To\YourFileName.xlsx", xlWorkbookDefault ' or other format
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to use some of this code as I transition from a "Full" paste down to a paste special values only.

Comment: @MattM just made a few improvements.  BTW do you need cell formats in the new workbook?

Comment: yes. For this exercise I'd like to keep the formatting from the source sheets, but remove all formulas, links etc...... I just want to create a "values only" version of the sheets from the original file

Comment: OK, thats what the posted code does (Note `xlPasteFormats` also pastes Conditional Formats, which I then remove. You can consider this step optional)

Comment: awesome. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the sheet numbers of what you want to copy (Which it seems you do from your post) you can simply copy them which will create a new book:

```
Sheets(array(1,3,5)).copy
```

This will copy sheets 1, 3 and 5 to a new workbook.

Alternatively if you want to select them first then run the macro this code will copy them to a new book:

```
Activeworkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets.copy
```

Then you can loop through the sheets in the new workbook like this:

```
Dim WS as worksheet
For each WS in worksheets
    cells.copy
    range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
next
```

This will copy then paste as value everything on each sheet.

I note you said in your comments that using `Activeworkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets` will do all sheets but it doesn't. I just created a new workbook, added 5 sheets, selected 1, 3 and 5 and ran this code, the resulting workbook was a new workbook with 3 sheets, Sheet1, Sheet3 and Sheet5.